# Build Pseudo Log table in SQL Server from Existing Table for a Record Attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, logging

I have a table that looks like:

```
ID1     EventID    EnterStatus   LeaveStatus
1       ABC43      2017-01-01    2017-01-05
1       F2C72      2017-01-03    2017-02-02
1       DBC42      2017-01-06    2017-02-02
2       96FUD      2017-01-03    2015-01-05
2       85YDZ      2017-01-07    NULL
```

Where the IDs represent and item than is either in status X or not in status X.

The EnterStatus and LeaveStatus fields are datetimes that mark whether something has happened to this item that cause it to be in Status X.

For example, for ID1,

- On 2017-01-01 eventID ABC43 happened that caused ID1 to enter status X.
- On  2017-01-03 eventID F2C72 happened that would have put it ID1 into status X, but it was already in status X, because ABC43 had not
  ended yet.
- On 2017-01-05 eventID ABC43 ended, but ID1 did not leave status X because eventID F2C72 had not ended yet.
- On 2017-01-06 event DBC42 happened, that would have put it ID1 into status X, but it was already in status X, because F2C72 had not ended
  yet.
- On 2017-02-02 both F2C72 and DBC42 ended, so ID1 left Status X.

What I'd like is a table that determines returns for each ID1 whether or not is was in status X or not in status. X

So that would look like

```
ID      EnterStatus   LeaveStatus  InStatusX
1        2017-01-01    2017-02-02   True
1        2017-02-02    NULL         False
2        2017-01-03    2015-01-05   True
2        2017-01-05    2015-01-07   False
2        2017-01-07    NULL         True
```

Any advice on the best way to query my table to return this new format?

Comment: i am having a hard time understanding the question. can you explain it better?

Comment: Updated, hope that helps!